# Microsoft Report builder does not show data in rows unless i change row height

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, report

Microsoft ReportBuilder seems to not want to show data in the rows when i preview it, UNLESS i change the height of every row.

BUILDER
[image]
PREVIEW :
**Notice the word "Total" does not show up in the preview**
[image]
BUILDER :
**Now i Will go and change the height of the row**
[image]
PREVIEW :
**Notice it now shows total**
[image]

This is only for the preview inside Report Builder(Microsoft product)
if i deploy the reports to my SSRS it works just fine.

**Question** :
is there a way to fix this ?